# Accessing global Sinatra object

Tags: ruby, sinatra, web-frameworks

I am trying to write a helper class in my Sinatra application. I'm trying to access Sinatra properties somehow but always getting `nil`. My code is as follows:

app.rb:

```
configure do
  enable :sessions
  set :session_secret, "STHSTHSTH"
  # DATABASE_URL is provided by environment, or can be set on the command line
  # For instance: DATABASE_URL=mysql://localhost/freecoins rackup
  # will run the app with the database at localhost/freecoins.
  DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
  # These set it up to automatically create/change tables when
  # their models are updated.
  DataMapper.auto_migrate!
  DataMapper.auto_upgrade!

  # Here we read in the config file and parse the JSON from it.
  config = JSON.parse(File.read("config/config.json"))

  # Then we loop through each element in the JSON object and
  # assign it to Sinatra's settings.
  # They are accessed via settings.key anywhere in the app,
  # especially in some of the routes.
  config.each do |k, v|
    set k.to_sym, v
  end
end

set :views,  'views'

Dir["routes/*.rb"].each {|file| require_relative file }
Dir["models/*.rb"].each {|file| require_relative file }
Dir["helpers/*.rb"].each {|file| require_relative file }

# This has to be called once all the models have been defined.
DataMapper.finalize
```

helper class:

```
class WalletHelper
    @currency = nil
    @client = nil
    def initialize(currency)
        puts $settings #settings is nil here
    end
end
```

How can I access properties of the app, settings for example, as I do in `get` blocks?

Comment: Where are you creating new `WalletHelper` object?

Answer (score 2):

You should try `Sinatra::Base.settings`

Comment: `Sinatra::Base.settings` is an object but different than the one I get in `get` blocks. It looks like an empty one.

Comment: If I use `Sinatra::Base.set` for setting them as well, then it works. Is this the best solution we can?

Answer (score 1):

you may want to see `Sinatra.register` and `Sinatra.helpers`

see http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html for more details